# ASA5500 series logging for management interface in transparent mode

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

i have a cisco asa5520 in transparent mode.  the interface is on the same subnet as some windows machines, which are generating a lot of broadcast traffic that is filling up the logs.

is there any way to have it not log that its blocking those packets? its a bunch of these messages: "through-the-device packet to from management-only network is denied: udp src..."

im also seeing some of those zeroconf requests that id like to drop logging for.

i tried to just put a rule on the management interface, but apparently thats not allowed.

it looks like turning the syslog filter up to error might solve both issues, but will i be missing any potentially life saving messages by ignoring the info bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - in syslog setup theres a list of syslog IDs. for this particular alert the ID number is 418001.  open that, click suppress, no more message in the log!